# RankNTypes and scope of `forall'

Tags: haskell, higher-rank-types

What is the difference between these?

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

f :: forall a. a -> Int
f _ = 1

g :: (forall a. a) -> Int
g _ = 1
```

In particular, why do I get an error with `g ()`?

```
ghci> f ()
1
ghci> g ()
<interactive>:133:3:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `()'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context: a at <interactive>:133:1
    In the first argument of `g', namely `()'
    In the expression: g ()
    In an equation for `it': it = g ()

ghci> f undefined
1
ghci> g undefined
1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`f` is just an ordinary polymorphic Haskell98 function, except the `forall` is written out explicitly. So all the type variables in the signature are parameters the caller gets to choose (without any constraints); in your case it's resolved `a ~ ()`.

`g` OTOH has a rank-2 type. It requires that its argument has the polymorphic type `forall a . a`. `()` does not have such a type, it is monomorphic. But `undefined` has this type (in fact, *only* undefined, and error etc.), if we add the explicit `forall` again.

Perhaps it becomes clearer with a less trivial Rank2 function:

```
h :: (forall a . (Show a, Num a) => a) -> String
h a = show a1 ++ " :: Double\n"
     ++ show a2 ++ " :: Int"
 where a1 :: Double; a2 :: Int
       a1 = a; a2 = a
```

> GHCi> putStrLn $ h 4
>   4.0 :: Double
>   4 :: Int

but I can't do

> GHCi> putStrLn $ h (4 :: Integer)
>   
>   <‌interactive>:4:15:
>       Could not deduce (a ~ Integer)
>       from the context (Show a, Num a)
>         bound by a type expected by the context: (Show a, Num a) => a
>         at <‌interactive>:4:12-27
>         `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
>             a type expected by the context: (Show a, Num a) => a
>             at <‌interactive>:4:12
>       In the first argument of `h', namely `(4 :: Integer)'
>       In the second argument of `($)', namely `h (4 :: Integer)'
>       In the expression: putStrLn $ h (4 :: Integer)

Comment: Are you saying that `()` is a monomorphism (in which category?) or are you saying that `()` is monomorphic to some other (unspecified) object? Or are you using the term 'monomorphic' in some other way?

Comment: @Snowball: I'm using the term in the way it's [usually](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) used in the context of Haskell: _something that is not polymorphic_. Actually, I've never thought about how this relates to monomorphisms...

Comment: I don't think there is any connection to the category theory concept of monomorphism.

Answer (score 11):

Think of `forall` as an anonymous type function. All data types in Haskell which have type variables in their type signature implicitly have a `forall`. For example consider:

```
f :: a -> Int
f _ = 1
```

The above function `f` takes an argument of any type and returns an `Int`. Where does the `a` come from? It comes from the `forall` quantifier. Hence it's equivalent to:

```
f :: (forall a . a -> Int)
f _ = 1
```

The `forall` quatifier can be used for any data type, not just functions. For example consider the types of the following values:

```
() :: ()
10 :: Int
pi :: Floating a => a
```

Here `()` and `10` are monomorphic (i.e. they can only be of one concrete type). On the other hand `pi` is polymorphic with a typeclass constraint (i.e. it can be of any type as long as that type is a instance of `Floating`). The type of `pi` written out explicitly is:

```
pi :: (forall a . Floating a => a)
```

Again the `forall` quantifier acts like a type function. It provides you the type variable `a`. Now consider the type of function `g`:

```
g :: (forall a . a) -> Int
g _ = 1
```

Here `g` expects an argument of type `forall a . a` and returns an `Int`. This is the reason `g ()` doesn't work: `()` is of type `()`, not of type `forall a . a`. In fact the only value of type `forall a . a` is `undefined`:

```
undefined :: a
```

Written out explicitly with `forall`:

```
undefined :: (forall a . a)
```

If you noticed I've always put parentheses around the `forall` quantifications. The reason I did this is to show you that when you use a `forall` quantification on a function the quantification extends all the way to the right. This is just like a lambda: if you don't put parentheses around the lambda Haskell will extend the lambda function all the way to the right. Hence the type of `f` is `(forall a . a -> Int)` and not `(forall a . a) -> Int`.

Remember in the first case Haskell expects the type of the argument to be `a` (i.e. anything). However in the second case Haskell expects the type of the argument to be `(forall a . a)` (i.e. `undefined`). Of course if you try to evaluate `undefined` then your program will immediately halt with an error. Fortunately you're not trying to evaluate it.

Comment: TLDR `forall's` can be viewed as lambdas at the type level and `\a -> M ~> N` isn't the same as `(\a -> M) ~> N`.

Comment: quote > Calling forall "a lambda at the type level" is inaccurate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10063020/1338198.