# RankNTypes and PolyKinds

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, higher-rank-types, polykinds

What is the difference between `f1` and `f2`?

```
$ ghci -XRankNTypes -XPolyKinds
Prelude> let f1 = undefined :: (forall a        m. m a -> Int) -> Int
Prelude> let f2 = undefined :: (forall (a :: k) m. m a -> Int) -> Int
Prelude> :t f1
f1 :: (forall            (a :: k) (m :: k -> *). m a -> Int) -> Int
Prelude> :t f2
f2 :: (forall (k :: BOX) (a :: k) (m :: k -> *). m a -> Int) -> Int
```

Related to this question on [RankNTypes and scope of forall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401018/rankntypes-and-scope-of-forall). Example taken from the GHC user's guide on [kind polymorphism](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`f2` requires its *argument* to be polymorphic in the kind `k`, while `f1` is just polymorphic in the kind itself. So if you define

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, PolyKinds #-}
f1 = undefined :: (forall a m. m a -> Int) -> Int
f2 = undefined :: (forall (a :: k) m. m a -> Int) -> Int
x = undefined :: forall (a :: *) m. m a -> Int
```

then `:t f1 x` types fine, while `:t f2 x` complains:

```
*Main> :t f2 x

<interactive>:1:4:
    Kind incompatibility when matching types:
      m0 :: * -> *
      m :: k -> *
    Expected type: m a -> Int
      Actual type: m0 a0 -> Int
    In the first argument of ‘f2’, namely ‘x’
    In the expression: f2 x
```

Comment: What exactly is `k` there ? is `k`  variable any special thing like `*` ?

Comment: @Sibi `k` is a kind variable, `*` is one of its possible "values". In Haskell types have kinds in much the same way as values have types, although you need extensions to use more than the builtin fixed kinds like `*` and `* -> *`.

Answer (score 11):

Let's be bloody. We must quantify everything and give the domain of quantification. Values have types; type-level things have kinds; kinds live in `BOX`.

```
f1 :: forall (k :: BOX).
      (forall (a :: k) (m :: k -> *). m a -> Int)
      -> Int

f2 :: (forall (k :: BOX) (a :: k) (m :: k -> *). m a -> Int)
      -> Int
```

Now, in neither example type is `k` quantified explicitly, so ghc is deciding where to put that `forall (k :: BOX)`, based on whether and where `k` is mentioned. I am not totally sure I understand or am willing to defend the policy as stated.

Ørjan gives a good example of the difference in practice. Let's be bloody about that, too. I'll write `/\ (a :: k). t` to make explicit the abstraction that corresponds to `forall`, and `f @ type` for the corresponding application. The game is that we get to pick the `@`-ed arguments, but we have to be ready to put up with whatever `/\`-ed arguments the devil may choose.

We have

```
x :: forall (a :: *) (m :: * -> *). m a -> Int
```

and may accordingly discover that `f1 x` is really

```
f1 @ * (/\ (a :: *) (m :: * -> *). x @ a @ m)
```

However, if we try to give `f2 x` the same treatment, we see

```
f2 (/\ (k :: BOX) (a :: k) (m :: k -> *). x @ ?m0 @ ?a0)
?m0 :: *
?a0 :: * -> *
where  m a = m0 a0
```

The Haskell type system treats type application as purely syntactic, so the only way that equation can be solved is by identifying the functions and identifying the arguments

```
(?m0 :: * -> *) = (m :: k -> *)
(?a0 :: *)      = (a :: k)
```

but those equations are not even well kinded, because `k` is not free to be chosen: it's being `/\`-ed not `@`-ed.

Generally, to get to grips with these uber-polymorphic types, it's good to write out all the quantifiers and then figure out how that turns into your game against the devil. Who chooses what, and in what order. Moving a `forall` inside an argument type changes its chooser, and can often make the difference between victory and defeat.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `f1` places more restrictions on its *definition*, while the type of `f2` places more restrictions on its *argument*.

That is: the type of `f1` requires its *definition* to be polymorphic in the kind `k`, while the type of `f2` requires its *argument* to be polymorphic in the kind `k`.

```
f1 :: forall (k::BOX). (forall          (a::k) (m::k->*). m a -> Int) -> Int
f2 ::                  (forall (k::BOX) (a::k) (m::k->*). m a -> Int) -> Int

-- Show restriction on *definition*
f1 g = g (Just True)  -- NOT OK. f1 must work for all k, but this assumes k is *
f2 g = g (Just True)  -- OK

-- Show restriction on *argument* (thanks to Ørjan)
x = undefined :: forall (a::*) (m::*->*). m a -> Int
f1 x  -- OK
f2 x  -- NOT OK. the argument for f2 must work for all k, but x only works for *
```